# How Can I Stack Div's/Containers With Multiple Classes?

Tags: html, css, containers

I am trying to put two of this thumbnail div next to one another.

The CSS is just for keeping my YouTube video in the borders.

I spent a while trying to search this today, but I have not found any articles that made sense to me, as a beginner in HTML, CSS, and Bootstrap code.

```css
.thumbnail iframe {
 padding-left: 3;
 padding-right: 3;
 padding-top: 3;
 padding-bottom: 3;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
      <div class="thumbnail">
        <iframe class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12" height="210" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/ZwpLEUOprd8" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
        <div class="caption">
          <h3>100 SUBSCRIBERS!!!!</h3>
          <p>We reached 100 subscribers!</p>
          <p><a target="_blank" href="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ZwpLEUOprd8" class="btn btn-primary" role="button">View On YouTube</a></p>
        </div>
   </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm very confused with what you are asking. You want to put two thumbnails next to each other? Where are the thumbnails in your code?

Comment: confusing question can you be more specific?

Comment: Run the code, I am trying to duplicate the code and horizontally position it next to the first code on the actual page. So, embedded YouTube video with description, and another YouTube video with description next to it. It's kind of hard for me to explain, so I apologize for any confusion...

Comment: @Aeth Did u check my answer? Please let me know if it resolved the problem

Answer (score 0):

You may take use of `display:inline-block;`:

```
.thumbnail{
    display: inline-block;
}
```

Another way would be to use `float`s, which may be some more tricky, as it has some drawbacks with some layouts.